# Maintained Xautolock alternative

Tags: linux, open-source

From the documentation:

> Xautolock  monitors  console activity  under the X window system, and
>   fires  up  a  program  of your choice if  nothing  happens  during  a
>   user configurable  period of time.  You can use this to automatically
>   start up a screen locker in case you tend to forget to do so manually
>   before having a coffee break.

My current usage:

1. [Lock Awesome WM desktop with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbd>](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/7f3270158be68a3f0c2d4abc304340bc0e780e42/.config/awesome/rc.lua#L336-L341):

   ```
   awful.key(
   { "Mod1", "Control" },
       "l",
       function ()
           awful.util.spawn("xautolock -locknow")
       end),
   ```
2. [Automatically lock desktop when idle, warning the user 30 seconds before doing so](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/7f3270158be68a3f0c2d4abc304340bc0e780e42/.xprofile#L58):

   ```
   xautolock -time 10 -notify 30 -notifier "notify-send --urgency low --expire-time=10000 -- 'Locking screen in 30 seconds'" -locker slock &
   ```

I've found a bug in Xautolock (the timing of `-time` and `-notify` seems to be off), but the program doesn't seem to be maintained, and it doesn't seem to have an official version controlled source repository. The only "reference" is [a directory](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/linux/X11/screensavers/). Is there an alternative, ideally compatible with [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server))?

Comment: Can you add a brief description of xautolock to your question?

Comment: xautolock has way too many bugs. I'm just switching to manual screen locking. (Though, one could feasibly code their own xautolock-lite within a few minutes, which should work much more reliably.)